# batch file.Write in file.How?

Tags: batch-file

i have text file, in file i have lines:

```
param1=text1

param2=text2
```

And i need write bat file, which modifies params value.

Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [DOS Batch - File Examples](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#Batch.FindAndReplace)

```
echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
:$changed 20100115
:$source http://www.dostips.com
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the names of the params, you can create the file complete with your values.

```
(
    echo set param1=value1
    echo set param2=myValue2
    echo set param3=myValue3
) > config.ini
```